# Graphing relativistic kinetic energy

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wrote a function that calculates relativistic kinetic energy but I'm having some problems graphing it. I'm working in Python Jupyter.

I'm using Taylor for very small values of *v* (so I don't end up with *E*=0 because of cancellation) and the original expression for the biggest values.
I have to calculate it for *v* between 1e-6 and 2.88e8.

```
m=1
c=3e8
def E(v):
    if (v/c) <= 0.8860:
        return ((m*v**2)/2) + ((3*m*v**4)/(8*c**2)) + ((5*m*v**6)/(16*c**4)) + ((35*m*v**8)/(128*c**6))
    else:
        return (m*c**2)*((1/sp.sqrt(1-(v**2/c**2)))-1)
```

This gives me very  accurate results.
Now the problem is graphing *E*(*v*). I have to use matplotlib (+ numpy and scipy for everything else). Here is what I wrote for a log-log graph.

```
xs = np.logspace(-6, 8.5)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[10,10])   
ax.plot(xs, E(xs))
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')
```

I am getting a value error :

```
 "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element
  is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()", and it points at "if (v/c) <= 0.8860:".
```

what's this error means and what I did wrong. I'd be very grateful if you could help me graph or change my function.

Comment: `v/c` is a vectorized operation in numpy, meaning that you get an _array_ of results (every value in `xs` is individually divided by `c` in the array). It doesn't make sense to compare an array to `<= 0.8860`. One way would be to use `numpy.where` to replace your if/else but I'm not able to test code atm to see if there's a more elegant approach.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a loop rather than just a condition:

```
m=1
c=3e8
def E(v):
    for i in range(len(v)):
        if (v[i]/c) <= 0.8860:
            return ((m*v**2)/2) + ((3*m*v**4)/(8*c**2)) + ((5*m*v**6)/(16*c**4)) + ((35*m*v**8)/(128*c**6))
        else:
            return (m*c**2)*((1/sp.sqrt(1-(v**2/c**2)))-1)


xs = np.logspace(-6, 8.5)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[10,10])   
ax.plot(xs, E(xs))
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')
```

The condition is expected a value for 'v' to compare to the 0.8860.
when presented with an array that has multiple values it says that it can't give True or False for an array.
all() and any() are methods to extract True or False from a list or an array:
any() will give True if any is True and all() will only if all is True.

Comment: There's a couple of issues here. First, `return` immediately breaks the `for` loop and second, you should not iterate through a numpy array unless necessary, otherwise just use a list.

Comment: you are right, @roganjosh. I quickly addressed he fact that there was an array of multiple values compared to a single value, but a loop makes little sense in the function body. I'll correct and add an answer that goes through the array outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

The statement `if (v/c) <= 0.8860` is not well defined, because for some values in `v` this is `True` for others it is `False`. This is a bit like asking "Are people taller than 1.8 meters?" There is no definitive answer; some are, some are not. The error tells you to specify exactly that: Do you want to know if all people are bigger or if any one person is bigger than 1.8m?  Here you want to actually know something else: You want for each entry a different result, depending on the condition.

You may use `numpy.piecewise` to define a function differently for certain conditions. Also mind that no entry of  `v` should be larger than `c` as this would result in an infinite energy.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m=1
c=3.e8

lowv = lambda v:((m*v**2)/2) + ((3*m*v**4)/(8*c**2)) + ((5*m*v**6)/(16*c**4)) + ((35*m*v**8)/(128*c**6))
highv = lambda v:(m*c**2)*(1./np.sqrt(1-(v/c)**2)-1)

E = lambda v : np.piecewise(v, [(v/c) <= 0.8860, (v/c) > 0.8860], [lowv,highv])

xs = 2.9999*np.logspace(-6, 8, num=1000)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[10,10])   
ax.plot(xs, E(xs))
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Alternatively you may use `numpy.vectorize` to make the existing function evaluated for each entry in  `v` individually. This is of course less efficient and should not be used for large arrays. Here is does not matter too much.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m=1
c=3.e8
def E(v):
    if (v/c) <= 0.8860:
        return ((m*v**2)/2) + ((3*m*v**4)/(8*c**2)) + ((5*m*v**6)/(16*c**4)) + ((35*m*v**8)/(128*c**6))
    else:
        return (m*c**2)*((1/np.sqrt(1-(v**2/c**2)))-1)

Ev = np.vectorize(E)

xs = 2.9999*np.logspace(-6, 8, num=1000)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[10,10])   
ax.plot(xs, Ev(xs))
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')

plt.show()
```